# Given two points inside a window frame (x0,y0 and x1,y1) - What method would you used to extend a line to the edges of the window?

Tags: java, math, pseudocode

For an introduction computer graphics paper I am struggling to extend a line defined by two points using the same gradient to the edge of the window. It's quite hard to explain so this image will likely help.

[image: IMG]

The dotted line is the part not defined by the line (x0,y0 to x1,y1).

We have tried a few things using the implicit equation of a line (ax+bx+c = 0) and finding an intersection point with the all four edges of the window frame.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first job is to check that `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` are distinct points.

The implicit equation of a non-vertical line is actually `y = mx + c` where the *gradient* `m` is `(y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)`, and `c` is the interception on the `y` axis, which can be found by applying `c = y1 - mx1` or `c = y0 - mx0`.

Once you have the values of `m` and `c`, you can apply the line equation to find the `y` points given your set of `x` points (or vice-versa), in order to plot the line to the desired length.

A vertical line is characterised by `x0` being equal to `x1`. In that case, your plot is simply a line that crosses the `x` axis at `x0`.

Also note that the line will only ever intercept with 2 edges (unless the line is collinear with one of the edges).

Comment: The collinearity case of a resulting vertical line (i. e. `x0 = x1`) you would have to handle in a special (but very easy) way. Otherwise you would face division by zero exceptions. For horizontal collinearity simply `m = 0`.

Comment: Just added this as you were writing your comment ;-)

Comment: Apologies, our lecture notes said ax + by + c was the implicit eqn of a line. Our issue is we need to deal with vertical lines, hence the usage of this equation.

Comment: I see, sorry. This just came to my mind as i remembered me struggling on this years ago. :)

Comment: @AnaRamire: that's a horrible way of specifying a line equation, IHMO naturally. If you do it my way, the gradient drops out more simply.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I agree, but this is done fairly often in mathematics, because it has some structural similarities with other curve definitions. @Ana Ramirez: `ax + by + c = 0` means: `by = ax + c` means `y = (a / b) * x + (c / b)`, so in `y = mx + n`: `m` means `a / b` and `n` means `c / b`.

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with the normal form of the line equation:

```
n = (y1-y0, x0-x1)
```

(n is the direction from one point to another rotated by 90°)

Equation for points `p` on the line:

```
p * n = (x0, y0) * n
```

or

```
(p - (x0, y0)) * n = 0
```

`*` denotes the scalar product above, but not below.

so the equation to solve is

```
(px - x0) * (y1 - y0) + (py - y0) * (x0 - x1) = 0
```

All coordinated but `px` and `py` (the x and y coordinates of the point) are given, and one of `px` and `py` is determined by the side you want to intersect. Beware of divisions by 0 however, if you're solving this equation (horizontal/vertical lines).

Answer (score 0):

When you have implicit equation

```
ax + by + c = 0
```

and window edges coordinates Left, Top, Right, Bottom (Left and Top might be zero), then you can substitute these coordinates into equation and check that calculated point doesn't exceed window's border.

For example, to get intersection with right edge, substitute `Right` x-coordinate

```
a * Right + b * y + c = 0
if b = 0 then
   no intersection (vertical)  
else
   y =  (a * Right + c ) / b    
check whether Top <= y <= Bottom
```